# What are the long term effects of dieting and maintaining a caloric deficit?

Tags: nutrition, diet, micronutrients

Are there any negative health risks for dieters assuming that you take a multivitamin, and other required supplements daily? The caloric deficit would end once the goal weight is achieved, which is how diets usually work, but unfortunately they can take a year or so to end.

Comment: Do you mean besides weight loss? Can you expand on this question (what negative effects are you wondering about?) without broadening it's already maybe too (e.g. does this include psychological effects?) broad scope? How far beyond weight loss to within a standard deviation of ideal body weight do you mean? A prolonged caloric deficit would ultimately lead to death. Seemingly straightforward questions are rarely so. Please limit the scope of this question. Thanks!